# Testing recurring payment in 2Checkout Sandbox

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I'm using the 2Checkout sandbox as a payment gateway. It is working fine with making the payment, start recurring, stop recurring, etc.

The problem is with the recurring URL testing, I've set up an INS URL(My website URL) from this URL(https://sandbox.2checkout.com/sandbox/notifications/).The thing is when I'm trying to test my recurring URL from (https://sandbox.2checkout.com/sandbox/notifications/ins_test) this test page.

It always says "Your test message has been queued for delivery, please allow several minutes for the message to be sent to your script." and nothing happens.

Any suggestion/help will be appreciated!

I'm expecting an array of response in my function, but nothing happens!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs this.

The mistake was from my end, The INS URL that I had entered was domain.com while it should be like this: www.domain.com/route.php.

This solved my issue.